# ListView get data from database and show in fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-listview

patientlist_listview.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

activity_icon_text_tabs.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"  />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

OneFragment.java

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments;

public class OneFragment extends Fragment {


private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patientlist_listview, container, false);

    return view;

}

}
```

IconTextTabactivity.java

```
public class IconTextTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
};


private static final String TAG = PatientList.class.getSimpleName();
// initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
private int offSet = 0;

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://192.168.0.102/test/apps.php";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<Patient>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter listadapter;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_icon_text_tabs);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    setContentView(R.layout.patientlist_listview);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

    listadapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, patientList);
    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
   // getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
    //        new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00BBD3")));

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    /**
     * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
     * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
     */
    swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                    fetchPatients();
                                }
                            }
    );

    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);

    // Click event for single list row
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(IconTextTabsActivity.this, "row " + position + " was pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    TextView c =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    String item = c.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("id", item);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    break;
            }

        }

    });


    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

/**
 * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
 */
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    fetchPatients();
}
/**
 * Fetching movies json by making http call
 */
private void fetchPatients() {

    // showing refresh animation before making http call
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    // appending offset to url
    //String url = URL_TOP_250 + offSet;

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();
                    Log.d("id", "hi") ;
                    // Parsing json
                    // reset the list
                    patientList.clear();
                    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length();i++) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("id","hi1") ;
                            Log.d("i","i:"+i);

                            Patient patient = new Patient();

                            Log.d("length", "length:" + response.length());
                            JSONObject objid= response.getJSONObject(i);
                            //get id
                            patient.setTitle(objid.getString("id"));


                            JSONObject objimage= response.getJSONObject(++i);
                            patient.setThumbnailUrl(objimage.getString("image"));
                            //Log.d("i","i:"+i);



                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);
                            */

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            if(i%2==1)
                                patientList.add(patient);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // stopping swipe refresh
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public PatientList() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}


//public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
 //                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  //  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.patientlist_listview, container, false);
//}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

I want to get the data from the database and set to the listview before showing the page to the tab. However, it crashed. The listview and tab project can run properly but i can't merge them and I got the following error . Please give me some help. Thx

```
01-11 01:22:04.467 10373-10373/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-11 01:22:04.917 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-11 01:22:04.934 10373-10373/info.androidhive.materialtabs D/Atlas: Validating map...
01-11 01:22:05.004 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-11 01:22:05.005 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-11 01:22:05.024 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-11 01:22:05.071 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-11 01:22:05.090 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-11 01:22:05.109 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-11 01:22:05.109 10373-10410/info.androidhive.materialtabs W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeed0d7c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-11 01:22:17.679 10373-10373/info.androidhive.materialtabs D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-11 01:22:17.680 10373-10373/info.androidhive.materialtabs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: info.androidhive.materialtabs, PID: 10373
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.materialtabs/info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.IconTextTabsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity.IconTextTabsActivity.onCreate(IconTextTabsActivity.java:80)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
01-11 01:27:17.701 10373-10373/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10373 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Means `tabLayout ` is `null` show `activity_icon_text_tabs ` xml code

Comment: @Ng Clement, please post your xml !!!

Comment: but I got return view in the OneFragment.java and have set the content of activity_icon_text_tabs in the onCreate. Right?